# Error while Reading from ServiceBus topic/subscription using Azure funtion

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm currently developing azure functions (new at it) but I'm getting the below error while trying to read from a topic/subscription. I have no idea what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
[20/12/2018 14:22:22] Loaded custom extension: ServiceBusExtensionConfig from 'referenced by: Method='Function.ContentCacheUpdate.ReadNotificationQueue.Run', Parameter='mySbMsg'.'
[20/12/2018 14:22:22] Generating 1 job function(s)
[20/12/2018 14:22:23] Found the following functions:
[20/12/2018 14:22:23] Function.ContentCacheUpdate.ReadNotificationQueue.Run
[20/12/2018 14:22:23]
[20/12/2018 14:22:23] Host initialized (1208ms)
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
[20/12/2018 14:22:23] Host started (1682ms)
[20/12/2018 14:22:23] Job host started
[20/12/2018 14:22:23] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000EB6A5850'.
```

My function looks like this

```
private const string TopicName = "testtopic";

[FunctionName("Function2")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger(TopicName, "SubscriptionName", Connection = "MyBindingConnection")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

and my local.settings.json file is

```
{
 "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "TopicName": "testtopic",
    "SubscriptionName": "testsubscription",
    "MyBindingConnection": "Endpoint=sb://test-.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you check is you are using the NuGet Package Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.ServiceBus? I think you need it in Azure Functions 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Azure Functions Core Tools used by VS is outdated. To fix this,

First, go to VS menus>Tools>Extensions and Updates, find `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`, update it if it's not the [latest](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md#release-notes)(15.10.2046.0 right now). Close all VS instances. Wait for the update to finish(if there is).

Then clean the old tools and templates and use VS to download new tools.

1. Remove `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools` and `%userprofile%\.templateengine` folder.
2. Reopen VS to create a new Function project, wait at the creation dialog, See `Making sure all templates are up to date...`.

   [image]
   After a while, we can see the tip changes as

   [image]
3. Click Refresh to work with the latest template instantly.

After creating a new v2 ServiceBus Topic trigger, change your code as below. `Connection` looks for value in app settings(local.setting.json) by default, while for others properties, we need to wrap them with percent sign. Check details in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings#binding-expressions---app-settings).

```
    [FunctionName("MyServiceBusTrigger")]
    public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "MyBindingConnection")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
    }
```

local.settings.json

```
{
 "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "TopicName": "testtopic",
    "SubscriptionName": "testsubscription",
    "MyBindingConnection": "Endpoint=sb://test-.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx="
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you represent that "TopicName,SubscriptionName,MyBindingConnection" (based on your example) in the appsettings.json. Do you still have to put it in a "Values" object in the appsettings.json file?

Comment: @Oneil Azure Functions use the `local.settings.json` and we need to put those settings in `Values` so they can be resolved. The code sample works exactly with the `local.settings.json` sample above.

Comment: Am i correct in saying the local.settings.json should only be used for development and the appsettings.json should be used for production?

Comment: @Oneil Partly, `local.settings.json` is for [local dev](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) and for production we use [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings) in portal other than a settings file.

Comment: So... because we have to use appSettings.json for production how do you represent the values in the local.settings.json file in the appSettings.json file? Do we still need to put the configuration in a "Values" object in the  appSettings.json file?

Comment: @Oneil Do you mind accepting the answer if you have solved the original problem in this post? We could carry on discussing in the new post.

Answer (score 0):

Even I did using this way,Can you cross check if there are messages in the subscription.